# GridView only shows 1 row even though multiple rows are returned

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView for which the datasource is a DataTable, populated by an SqlDataAdapter.  I've tested the SQL query multiple times with multiple criteria in SQL Management Studio and returned multiple rows in a dataset, however when the data is bound to the GridView on my ASP.NET page, only the first row displays where there should be several rows.

Other solutions to this problem had to do with the OnRowDataBound event, however I don't use that event.

Any pointers on making my code (especially my SQL query) more effective/efficient would be appreciated as well.

UPDATE: The query seems to return multiple results when the query is executed with the following parameters but at other time: assignment = 2 requesttype = OT otcode = 3

Here is the ASP.NET page with the search criteria (textboxes and dropdownlists) and the GridView in question:

```
<div>
    <label id="lblCardNumber" for="tbCardNumber">Card number</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCardNumber"></asp:TextBox>
    <Label ID="lblUsername" for="tbUsername">Username</Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbUsername"></asp:TextBox>
    <Label ID="lblAssignment" for="ddlAssignment">Assignment</Label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="textbox" ID="ddlAssignment">
        <asp:ListItem Value='NULL' Text='Select' />
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text='1' />
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text='2' />
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text='3' />
        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text='4' />
        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text='5' />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <Label ID="lblRequestType" for="ddlRequestType">Request Type</Label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlRequestType">
        <asp:ListItem Value="NULL" Text="select" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="All" Text="All" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="OT" Text="OT" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="CO" Text="CO" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="TR" Text="TR" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="EP" Text="EP" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="TO" Text="TO" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div id="OTSubTypes" class="subtypes OT">
        <label for="ddlOTCode">ot code no.</label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="textbox" ID="ddlOTCode">
            <asp:ListItem Value='0' Text='Select' />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="COSubTypes" class="subtypes CO">
        <label for="rblCourtSession">Court Session</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblCourtSession">
            <asp:ListItem>morning</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>afternoon</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>standby</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <label for="rblCourtType">Court Type</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblCourtType">
            <asp:ListItem>superior</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ygc</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>traffic</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <label for="rblAppearanceType">Appearance Type</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblAppearanceType">
            <asp:ListItem>trailing</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>da Conference</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>administrative hearing</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <div id="TRSubTypes" class="subtypes TR">
        <label for="ddlTrainingCode">Training Code</label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="textbox" ID="ddlTrainingCode">
            <asp:ListItem Value='0' Text='Select' />
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <Label ID="lblBeginningDate" for="tbBeginningDate">Beginning Date</Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbBeginningDate"></asp:TextBox>
    <Label ID="lblAccountNumber" for="tbAccountNumber">Account Number</Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbAccountNumber"></asp:TextBox>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="search" OnClick="btnSearchClick" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClearFields" Text="clear fields"/>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" class="table table-striped table-hover" ID="gvSearchResults" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="card_number" HeaderText="Card Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestType" HeaderText="Card Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="beginning_date" HeaderText="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status_id" HeaderText="Status" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        edit
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%#Eval("RequestType") %>Request.aspx?id=<%#Eval("card_number") %>">edit/view</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Here is the c#:

```
protected void btnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeHubDBCS"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        //declare parameters that are independent of request type
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CardNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbCardNumber.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbUsername.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Assignment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlAssignment.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BeginningDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbBeginningDate.Text;

        //declare sqlcommand arguments and parameters that are dependent on request type
        switch (ddlRequestType.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "co":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchCORequests", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourtSession", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rblCourtSession.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourtType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rblCourtType.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppearanceType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rblAppearanceType.SelectedValue;
                break;
            case "ep":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchEPRequests", conn);
                break;
            case "ot":

                cmd.CommandText = "spSearchOTRequests";
                //cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchOTRequests", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbAccountNumber.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlOTCode.SelectedValue;
                break;
            case "pt":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchPTRequests", conn);
                break;
            case "to":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchTORequests", conn);
                break;
            case "tr":
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchTRRequests", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrainingCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlTrainingCode.SelectedValue;
                break;
        }

        SqlDataAdapter daSearchResults = new SqlDataAdapter();
        daSearchResults.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dtSearchResults = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            daSearchResults.Fill(dtSearchResults);

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            message = "search error: ";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + ex.Message + "');", true);
        }

        gvSearchResults.DataSource = dtSearchResults;
        gvSearchResults.DataBind();

        gvSearchResults.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gvSearchResults.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

Here is the SQL query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spSearchOTRequests
@CardNumber VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,
@Username VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,
@Assignment VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,
@BeginningDate VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,
@AccountNumber VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,
@OTCode VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL   
AS
BEGIN
    SET @CardNumber = ISNULL(@CardNumber, '')
    SET @Username = ISNULL(@Username, '')
    SET @Assignment = ISNULL(@Assignment, '')
    SET @BeginningDate = ISNULL(@BeginningDate, '')
    SET @AccountNumber = ISNULL(@AccountNumber, '')
    SET @OTCode = ISNULL(@OTCode, '')

    IF @CardNumber = '' BEGIN SET @CardNUmber = @CardNumber + '%' END
    IF @Username = '' BEGIN SET @Username = @Username + '%' END
    IF @Assignment = '' BEGIN SET @Assignment = @Assignment + '%' END
    IF @BeginningDate = '' BEGIN SET @BeginningDate = @BeginningDate + '%' END
    IF @AccountNumber = '' BEGIN SET @AccountNumber = @AccountNumber + '%' END
    IF @OTCode = '' BEGIN SET @OTCode = @OTCode + '%' END

    SELECT
        card_number,
        UserCredited,
        user_star,
        assignment,
        beginning_date,
        event_number,
        ot_code,
        status_id,
        RequestType
    FROM dbo.OTCard
    WHERE
        (@CardNumber IS NULL OR (@CardNumber = '') OR (card_number LIKE @CardNumber))
        AND (@Username IS NULL OR (@Username = '') OR (UserCredited LIKE @Username))
        AND (@Assignment IS NULL OR (@Assignment = '') OR (assignment LIKE @Assignment))
        AND (@BeginningDate IS NULL OR (@BeginningDate = '') OR (beginning_date LIKE @BeginningDate))
        AND (@AccountNumber IS NULL OR (@AccountNumber = '') OR (event_number LIKE @AccountNumber))
        AND (@OTCode IS NULL OR (@OTCode = '') OR (ot_code LIKE @OTCode))

    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
END
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `gvSearchResults.DataSource = dtSearchResults;`, then how many items are in the `DataTable` object (`dtSearchResults.Rows.Count`)?

Comment: dtSearchResults.Rows.Count shows 1 item.  I find this strange since if I am in SQL Mgmt Studio and perform a simple 'EXECUTE' command using the same parameters as in the web app, that same query returns 5 rows of data.

Comment: n you drop down you have the first option is NULL this when sent to the store procedure will be as a text 'NULL' not a null value Try this one instead

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Assignment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlAssignment.SelectedValue == "NULL" ? null : ddlAssignment.SelectedValue;

Comment: @AladinHdabe - I'lll change the initial value of the assignment dropdown.  The issue in question though occurs even when there is a selection made in that dropdownlist.

Comment: How about the ddlOTCode , the default value is 0, when you test the sp on sql server do you pass 0 as well?

Comment: @AladinHdabe - So far, I have been running the queries without providing a value for OTcode, so the stored procedure is executed with OTCode = ''.  This doesn't seem to be causing the issue though.  I'm almost certain that the issue has to do with the sqlDataAdapter only reading the first row returned (see my reply to Karl Anderson's question above), though I can't pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: Try to use SqlDataReader like reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() then do dtSearchResults.Load(reader) and see what happened and take them out of the try catch block

Comment: @AladinHdabe - changed to a datareader and removed the try-catch block.  Results are the same.  didn't fix the issue.

Comment: UPDATE:  The query seem to return multiple results when the query is executed with the following parameters but no other times:
assignment = 2
requesttype = OT
otcode = 3

Comment: What do you mean? The same parameters values but different result in the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

In you dropdown you have the first option 
This when sent to the store procedure will be as a text 'NULL' not a null value
Try this one instead

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Assignment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlAssignment.SelectedValue == "NULL" ? null : ddlAssignment.SelectedValue;
```

First you need to make sure that more that one record is returned from the procedure, you can break after you fill the dtSearchResults and check how many records it contains.
If the table contains more than one rows and the grid displays one row check the html output of the table using the browser inspector maybe the css styles has some to do with it.

For the SQL query
these conditions

```
(@CardNumber    IS NULL OR  (@CardNumber    =   ''  )
(@Username      IS NULL OR  (@Username      =   ''  )
(@Assignment    IS NULL OR  (@Assignment    =   ''  )
(@BeginningDate IS NULL OR  (@BeginningDate =   ''  )
(@AccountNumber IS NULL OR  (@AccountNumber =   ''  )
(@OTCode        IS NULL OR  (@OTCode        =   ''  )
```

they never going to be true since you convert NULL and Empty parameters and to % at the binning of the sp so you should get ready of them

I see all parameters are varchar(max) is this the datatype in the table as well?

You can try to use parameterized dynamic sql

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL =' SELECT
    card_number     ,
    UserCredited    ,
    user_star       ,
    assignment      ,
    beginning_date  ,
    event_number    ,
    ot_code         ,
    status_id       ,
    RequestType
FROM dbo.OTCard 
WHERE 1=1 '

IF ISNULL(@CardNumber,'') <>''
   SET @SQL=@SQL+' AND card_number LIKE @CardNumber'
IF ISNULL(@Username,'') <>''
   SET @SQL=@SQL+' AND UserCredited LIKE @Username'
   Continue with the rest of the parameters
  ....
  ....

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,
N'@CardNumber VARCHAR(MAX),@Username  VARCHAR(MAX),@Assignmen VARCHAR(MAX),@BeginningDate VARCHAR(MAX),@AccountNumber VARCHAR(MAX), @OTCode VARCHAR(MAX)',
@CardNumber,@Username,@Assignment,@BeginningDate,@AccountNumber ,@OTCode
```

For parameter sniffing issue you can use OPTION  (RECOMPILE) inside the @SQL

Or if you have some parameters that when the value changed it will change the execute plan dramatically and you want the cost of recompile each time you can use somthing like this

```
declare @HashKey varbinary(20)
    select @HashKey= HASHBYTES('SHA1', @Username )  you can concatenate more parameters if you wish
    SET @SQL='declare @HashKey nvarchar(200)
    SET @HashKey='''+ CONVERT(nvarchar(100),@HashKey,1 )+'''
    '+@SQL
```

Add it before EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL